# eclipse and maven downloading a lot of packages

Tags: eclipse, maven

I tried to follow this tutorial that uses Gradle on Eclipse then Eclipse started downloading a lot packages. Then I switched to Maven version of the same project since I have Maven installed on my machine. Eclipse is doing the same thing with Maven.

The project is a very small Spring Boot project. Why is eclipse stil downloading tons of packages from Maven? Also who's doing the downloading? Eclipse or Maven? I'm new to these build tools.

Comment: It's Maven downloading all the dependencies for the project.  I'm guessing the spring packages and any other packages it depends on.

Comment: @admdev Welcome to Java world! But don't worry, Maven has a local repository of packages, so next time it won't download them all again, only the ones that were actually updated.

Comment: Thank you all. Now it's telling me one of the dependencies has a problem and it won't be updated again until the central updates or force update because it's cached!!! what does that mean and how to fix?

Comment: @howlger link broken?

Comment: Maven downloads the internet: http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/04/how-not-to-download-the-internet/

Comment: @pirho Yes, thx. This should work: http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/04/how-not-to-download-the-internet/

Comment: @admdev The cached files are in your local Maven repository (on Windows by default in `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository`). If you delete some directories or the whole repository, the files will be downloaded again.

Comment: Thank you deleting the repository worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this maven build for the first time, it will download the dependencies required by your project and their transitive dependencies too and store in your local repository. The next time you run the build, the local dependencies will be used.